# Does it make sense to have nested setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've stumbled upon the below code and I'm wondering if it make any differences.

```js
this.setState({ name: xx }, () => this.setState({ age: 17 }))
```

vs

```js
this.setState({ name: xx, age: 17 });
```

Are they exactly the same thing or the first way will actually making sure `name` state to be updated first, and forcing a re-render before update state `age`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It makes sense to have nested state.

Nested State update ensures that:

```
The state of first variable is updated.
The component is updated (re-rendered).
The state of second variable is updated.
The component is updated (re-rendered) again.
```

To test this, I've added both the above cases in a react project. Check the repo here:

```
https://github.com/kramankishore/React-Nested-State
```

To test if the component is being re-rendered, I have added a console log in shouldComponentUpdate() function.

Component update happens in the following order:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps()
shouldComponentUpdate()
render()
getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()
componentDidUpdate()
```

When you check console logs in the browser, in the normal case, you can see 'Rerender triggered!' being logged only once. But in the nested case, you can see it being logged twice indicating that the component is updated twice.

Here is the code of the component in case you want to try:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class NestedState extends Component {
  state = {
    var1: 0,
    var2: 0,
    var3: 0,
    var4: 0
  };

  incrementHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ var1: this.state.var1 + 1, var2: this.state.var2 + 1 });
  };

  incrementHandlerNested = () => {
    this.setState({ var3: this.state.var3 + 1 }, () =>
      this.setState({ var4: this.state.var4 + 1 })
    );
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    console.log("Rerender triggered!");
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Normal</h1>
        <a>{this.state.var1}</a>
        <a>{this.state.var2}</a>
        <div />
        <button onClick={this.incrementHandler}>Increment</button>
        <h1>Nested</h1>
        <a>{this.state.var3}</a>
        <a>{this.state.var4}</a>
        <div />
        <button onClick={this.incrementHandlerNested}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NestedState;
```

Normal case output (in browser console):

```
Rerender triggered!
```

Nested case output (in browser console):

```
Rerender triggered!
Rerender triggered!
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState({ name: xx }, () => this.setState({ age: 17 }))
```

With this you can make sure that age is set to 17 only after name is set to xx. But in latter it can happen in same time or any order as setState is asyncronous.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways will work, but the question is why do you need that?
Thats will cost you a new render. Of course if you will not prevent that.

Comment: Exactly and thats the code I've stumbled upon. So my objective is to find out if there's something I never thought of